# how to select active inputs in jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

I have two inputs

```
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
```

I want the one that I have currently selected to have a red background (I have to use jQuery for this), however

```
$("input:selected").css("background-color", "red")
```

or

```
$(":selected").css("background-color", "red")
```

Both are not working. Does anyone know a fix that doesn't involve calling a function with `.click`? See https://jsfiddle.net/qtokpgv5/ for demo.

`:focus` is also not working

Answer (score 3):

You should be using CSS for this, not JS. `:focus` is exactly what you need, and works fine:

```css
input:focus {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
```

If you did want to use jQuery for this, which is not a good idea, then you could use the `focus` and `blur` event handlers:

```js
$('input').on({
  focus: function() {
    $(this).addClass('focus');
  },
  blur: function() {
    $(this).removeClass('focus');
  }
});
```

```css
.focus {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the `:focus` selector in CSS, rather than javascript to achieve this:

```css
input:focus {
  outline:2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
```

If you're working within requirements that strictly require a javascript based approach, then the following jQuery illustrates how this behaviour can be replicated with javascript:

```js
$(document)
.on('focus', 'input', function() {
 
  // Apply outline to show focus
  $(this).css({ outline : '1px solid red'})
})
.on('blur', 'input', function() {
 
  // Remove outline to show loss of focus
  $(this).css({ outline : ''})
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
```

Comment: how does this differ from Rory's answer? :)

Comment: Looks like he posted his answer just before I did - I've extended mine to demonstrate a js based approach as well (in case these are specific requirements for the OP)

Answer (score 0):

This changes the background color with jquery. However, it is better to use css for this as the other answers suggest.

```js
$('input').on('focus', function() {
  $(this).css("background-color", "red");
});

$('input').on('focusout', function() {
  $(this).css("background-color", "");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
```